# How to resume app from remote push notification click

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using firebase to send push notifications from a server to my app, the message looks like this:

```
var message = new Message()
            {
                Notification = new Notification()
                {
                    Title = "Title - Test",
                    Body = "Body - Test",
                    
                },

                Token = registrationToken
            };
```

The notification comes through to the device no problem. All I want from when the notification is clicked, is for the app to start if the app is closed (this works) and for the app to resume if it's in the background.

When it's in the background and I click the notification, I just get a white screen. The issue seems to go away when I remove my splash screen, however that is not an ideal solution...Here is the relevant code, what am I doing wrong?

SPLASH ACTIVITY:

```
[Activity(Label = "MyApp",
        Theme = "@style/splashscreen",
        MainLauncher = true,
        NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();

            var mainActivityIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            mainActivityIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop | ActivityFlags.NoAnimation);
            StartActivity(mainActivityIntent);
            this.Finish();
        }

        public override void OnBackPressed() { }
    }
```

MAIN ACTIVITY:

```
[Activity(Label = "MyApp",
        Theme = "@style/MainTheme",
        LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop,
        MainLauncher = false,
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.FullSensor)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        public static MainActivity MainActivityInstance { get; private set; }
    
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            this.Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn, WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);
            this.Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustPan);

            Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            MainActivityInstance = this;

            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding ActivityFlags.ClearTop to mainActivityIntent.AddFlags() in my OnResume method on
SplashActivity has seemed to have worked:

```
protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();

            var mainActivityIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            mainActivityIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NoAnimation | ActivityFlags.SingleTop | ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
            StartActivity(mainActivityIntent);
            this.Finish();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `MainLauncher = true` for the main activity.

Comment: Hey Hasitha, thanks for the answer. It works but it results in having two launcher icons (at least in debug) which is not ideal.